# Checking the last character of a filename in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that checks whether the user accidentally added an extra "/" to the end of a filepath (eg. MY_PATH) and if they did, it removes the last character.  My script (see below) does successfully remove the last character of a path, but for some reason it also sometimes removes the last character even if it isn't "/".  Does anyone know why it is doing this or how to fix it?  I am open to alternative solutions.

```
MY_PATH="~/directory/Rscript.R"
#MY_PATH="~/directory/Rscript.R/"
if [ "${MY_PATH:$((${#MY_PATH}-1)):${#MY_PATH}}"=="/" ]
    then MY_PATH=${MY_PATH:0:$((${#MY_PATH}-1))}; fi
echo ${MY_PATH}
```

Comment: The original problem is that you need spaces around `==`. Also, it really should be `=` in a `[ ]` test, and `~` doesn't expand inside quotes, and you should double-quote `${MY_PATH}` in the final line.

Answer (score 1):

The last character of a string is accessed by `${MY_PATH: -1}`. You can test it as

```
if test ${MY_PATH: -1} = / ; then
```

or

```
if [ ${MY_PATH: -1} = / ]; then
```

or

```
if [[ ${MY_PATH: -1} = / ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ ${MY_PATH: -1} == / ]]; then
```

or

```
if [[ ${MY_PATH: -1} =~ / ]]; then
```

The first three alternatives use string comparision, the 4th one wildcard matching, and the last one regex matching. Most of the spaces in those alternatives matter, so be sure that you get the spaces right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`

```
MY_PATH=$(sed 's#\/$##g' <<< ${MY_PATH})
```

Demo:

```
$MY_PATH="~/directory/Rscript.R/"
$MY_PATH=$(sed 's#\/$##g' <<< ${MY_PATH})
$echo $MY_PATH 
~/directory/Rscript.R
$MY_PATH="~/directory/Rscript.R"
$MY_PATH=$(sed 's#\/$##g' <<< ${MY_PATH})
$echo $MY_PATH 
~/directory/Rscript.R
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the last character by

```sh
if [[ ${MY_PATH:(-1)} = '/' ]]; then
  ...
fi
```